# How to force a new FCM token on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to force a new token for the user but it does not work.

- The Old token still works
- The new token does not work

Am I missing anything?
I followed other Stack questions, most are outdated and old, the new ones are incorrect.

Firebase SDK 7.11.0

```
Installations.installations().delete { error in
        debugPrint("InstallationsDEL Installations delete: \nERROR: \(error)")
        
        Installations.installations().authTokenForcingRefresh(true) { result, error in
            debugPrint("InstallationsDEL Installations authTokenForcingRefresh: \nERROR: \(error) \nResult: \(result)")
            
           
            Messaging.messaging().deleteToken { error in
                print("InstallationsDEL Messaging.messaging().deleteToken: ERROR: \(error)")

                Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
                    debugPrint("InstallationsDEL Messaging.messaging().token: \(token) \n\nerror: \(error)")

                    print("")
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a little bit late response, but maybe will help someone:

FirMessaging function

```
- (void)deleteTokenWithCompletion:(FIRMessagingDeleteFCMTokenCompletion)completion
```

allows you to delete the default FCM registration token. So using Swift's

```
Messaging.messaging().deleteToken(completion: @escaping(Error?) -> Void)
```

for example

```
    Messaging.messaging().deleteToken { error in
     .
     .
     .
}
```

you can actually force Firebase to refresh token. To retrieve a new one, simply call

```
let token = try await Messaging.messaging().token()
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete your app from your device and then re-run it from Xcode.

It will then give you a new FCM token.

No need to force it from code.